# Simulated read denied in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm building a private note app in Firebase realtime database, Android environment,
and now, I'd like to add authentificaion features with google sign-in in my app.

Until now, I tried several Rules in 'Rules playground', but it's not working well.

DB is like following:

```
{
  "items" : {
    "-MwtOrIBmhaoiGtSjzRl" : {
      "key" : "-MwtOrIBmhaoiGtSjzRl",
      "modifiedAt" : "2022-02-27 04:19:15.782677",
      "string" : "test11"
    },
    "-MwvRBvCJ3hVJS3Qx1M3" : {
      "key" : "-MwvRBvCJ3hVJS3Qx1M3",
      "modifiedAt" : "2022-02-27 13:48:43.081140",
      "string" : "Test2"
    }
  }
}
```

And the rules are like following:

```
{
  "rules":{
    "items": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        },
      ".indexOn": "modifiedAt" 
    }
  }
}
```

In Rules playground, I tried 'get' simulation and the result is
'Simulated read denied'

```
{
  "auth": {
    "uid": "e41ac05f-6c93-40c8-add6-90bccf8ab80d",
    "token": {
      "sub": "e41ac05f-6c93-40c8-add6-90bccf8ab80d",
      "firebase": {
        "sign_in_provider": "google.com"
      },
      "email": "",
      "email_verified": false,
      "phone_number": "",
      "name": ""
    }
  },
  "resource": {
    "key": "value"
  },
  "path": "/item",
  "method": "get",
  "time": "2022-02-27T14:44:13.766Z",
  "isAdmin": false
}
```

Can I get some help?

One strange thing is that the follwing rules are not working well also.

```
{
  "rules":{
    "items": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
        },
      ".indexOn": "modifiedAt" 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The item key does not seem to be user's UID?  What kind of rules are you looking for?

Comment: 'Rules' means firebase database rules in json format. And, the item key is inserted manually for managing items easily by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key values you have under items are not Firebase Auth UIDs.  They are push IDs randomly generated from your client app code.  A push ID has nothing to do with the identity of the person who added that data.

To be clear, this value: "MwtOrIBmhaoiGtSjzRl" is not a UID.  And it doesn't match the UID you're specifying here: "e41ac05f-6c93-40c8-add6-90bccf8ab80d".

If you want to use the user's UID as the key of the data to add to the database, don't use `push()`.  You should instead build a path to the data using the user's UID in your code using `setValue()` as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write).

Comment: I don't want to use UID as a key. It's authentification issue. I want to use my realtime database in locked mode, and currently if I set the database ruless such as above in the body, then read/write operation denied by server.

Comment: If the UID isn't stored in your database, then you have no way of writing a rule to limit access based on that UID.

Comment: After I made a child node with a name as UID, I could successfully access the database. Thanks a lot!